# Understanding PHP for loop

Tags: php

I have a problem understanding how is the result 34 when it should be 32.Because the loop run's 4 times so when u add up 8 to the variable age it should bring up the sum as 32.Maybe I'm wrong please help out to understand.TQ

```
  <?php
    $age=24;
    for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++){
        $age= $age + 2;
    }
    echo ("At the end of the loop age = $age" );
  ?>
Result >>>>>>At the end of the loop age = 34
```

Comment: Well `24 + (2+2+2+2+2) = 34` The loop runs 5 time i.e. 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: The loop runs 5 times, not 4. Where `$i` equals `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. If you want it to run 4 times, then change the `$i <= 4` to just `$i < 4`.

Comment: Thank You @RiggsFolly@Dipen Shah@Jonathan Kuhn

Comment: Adding an `echo` inside the loop and you would have seen it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is not running four times; it's running five times.

$i<4 means the loop will terminate when $i reaches four - it terminates *before* that execution happens.  $i<=4 means "continue looping so long as $i is less than *or equal to* four"

So, let's work through the examples:
`for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++)`

- Begins, sets $i to value of 0
- Loop: is $i less than or equal to 4? $i=0, so yes.  $age += 2. ($age now equals 26).
- End of first loop: $i++ ($i now equals 1).
- Loop: is $i less than or equal to 4? $i = 1, so yes.  $age += 2; ($age now equals 28).
- End of second loop: $i++ ($i now equals 2).
- Loop; is $i less than or equal to 4? $i = 2, so yes.  $age += 2; ($age now equals 30).
- End of third loop: $i++ ($i now equals 3).
- Loop; is $i less than or equal to 4? $i = 3, so yes.  $age += 2; ($age now equals 32).
- End of fourth loop: $i++ ($i now equals 4).
- Loop; is $i less than or equal to 4? $i = 4, so yes -- **$i is equal to four, as specified by `<=`**.  $age += 2; ($age now equals 36).
- End of fifth loop: $i++ ($i now equals 5).
- Loop; is $i less than or equal to 4? $i = 5, so **no**.  Loop terminates.

Final result: $age = 36

Comment: Thank You @cegfault

Answer (score 1):

> The number of elements between 0 and positive N is N+1.

- You loop through 0 1 2 3 4.
- Those are 5 iterations.
- 24 + (2*5) = 34.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because the loop starts from 0, so it runs 5 times (0,1,2,3,4).

```
Loop 1 (when value is 0): 24 + 2 = 26;
Loop 2 (when value is 1): 26 + 2 = 28; 
Loop 3 (when value is 2): 28 + 2 = 30; 
Loop 4 (when value is 3): 30 + 2 = 32; 
Loop 5 (when value is 4): 32 + 2 = 34;
```

you can either start with 1 as:

```
for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
```

or make it < 4 instead of <= 4, as:

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

the loop runs from i=0 to i=4
i          age
0          26
1          28
2          30
3          32
4          34 ------>loop stops when i=5 since 5<=4 turns false
5
it should be

```
<?php
$age=24;
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    $age= $age + 2;
}
                   echo ("At the end of the loop age = $age" );
```

?>

the loop runs from i=0 to i=3
i          age
0          26
1          28
2          30
3          32 ------>loop stops when i=4 since 4<4 turns false
4
5